# Reverting Kotlin to Java codes in Android Studio Canary 5

Tags: java, android-studio, plugins, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

I'm making an Android app coding in Java just like everybody else's do. Since Android Studio 3.o Canary was released and adding support for Kotlin, I took a chance to give a try. Downloaded the plugins and setup the Gradle file correctly.
But once the activity is converted into Kotlin and synced, an error occured.
Below is my build.gradle,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

and,

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3'
```

Dependencies, [[image: 1]]

So, Im thinking to go back to Java until the issue is solved.

The Kotlin code are,

```
class Welcome : AppCompatActivity() {

internal var rujuk = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference        /*3rd step, DB reference*/
/*4th, initially write under onStart method, then CnP here, value inside child() should be same as in DB.*/
internal var referKpdTeksView = rujuk.child("intro")

@BindView(R.id.buku) internal var buku: ImageView? = null
@BindView(R.id.wel) internal var teksTajuk: TextView? = null /*1st step, declare variable for each Text*/

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome)
    ButterKnife.bind(this)
    rujuk.keepSynced(true)

    Glide.with(this).load("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/travel-and-go-93552.appspot.com/o/buku.png?alt=media&token=bad59236-e4ff-44e0-81ac-32adf9c1aea4").diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).into(buku!!)


}

@OnClick(R.id.enterButton)
fun g() {
    val EnterButton = Intent(this@Welcome, CountryList::class.java)
    startActivity(EnterButton)
}


/*5th step, create onStart method*/
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    /*DB reference 4th step
    * Syntax;
    * DatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener)*/
    referKpdTeksView.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val ayat = dataSnapshot.getValue(String::class.java)
            teksTajuk!!.text = ayat
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {

        }
    })
}
}
```

and the error is,

*Error:Failed to delete original file 'C:\Users\MohdA\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle_download1285409691272083864bin' after copy to 'C:\Users\MohdA.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.databinding\compilerCommon\2.3.3\1f0e06d55f3f72f3192b6e026d9a5a557d9e2ea6\compilerCommon-2.3.3.jar'*

Comment: Could you post the converted activity's code and the error?

Comment: Why don't you post your error to keep kotlin and get the error solved?

Comment: Try gradle clean and reboot your machine. That might solve the error. It's not related to Kotlin, but to the Gradle build system.

Comment: @ChristianBrüggemann already tried clean rebuild and make project. Still the same. What's wrong with gradle? Any idea?

Comment: You really don't need the `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"` dependency in your root gradle file.

Comment: Also and this is important you need to use the android gradle plugin version 3.0.0-alpha5: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha5'`

Comment: @NageshSusarla Ive tried with gradle 4 before, got problems with the gradle itself. that's why I used the stable one, and I also open the project with Stable AS. Removing that classpath giving more errors in custom library. The thing is, I just wanna know how to back to Java instead facing this error with kotlin plugins.

Answer (score 2):

In intellij i resolved by going through show history , project right click local history then show history

[image]